# StringTokenizer separate tokens using a char

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

How do I separate tokens in a StringToekenizer object taking a string s as a parameter?

so:

```
String s = input.readLine();
char tokenSeparator = ' '; //can be any value other than white space.
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
//separate tokens by the variable char tokenSeparator;
while (str.hasMoreTokens) ...
```

Comment: Did you try it? Does it give you what you want? If not, what's the problem you faced?

Comment: Why are you using `StringTokenizer` instead of `split`?

Comment: Just a requirement of an assignment.

Comment: Your professor wants you to use a deprecated class?

Comment: This class is not deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer). You can see a parameterized constructor as

```
public StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)
```

This is what you require here.

#### Example

```
String msg = "http://100.15.111.60:80/";
char tokenSeparatpor = ':';
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msg,tokenSeparatpor+"");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

#### Output

```
http
//100.15.111.60
80/
```

Comment: I know the parameters of StringTokenizer are (String,String) but can I modify the delim to be a one character string that is char tokenSeparator?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its
>   use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality
>   use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

Use `String.split()`, i.e.:

```
String s = input.readLine();
String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
```